# Change Frame properties with javascript in the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the size of an iframe with javascript according to the URL,

I mean that if the url is:

`mywebpage.com/example.html?width=800&height=450`

the iframe is

`<iframe width="800" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="http://mips.tv/embedplayer/test121/1/800/450"></iframe>`

See that the width and height values are twice each in the iframe

I have an example here but its now working in the src values of the iframe

http://redzeronline.ucoz.com/xd.html?width=800&height=450

Comment: your link is broken/404

Answer (score 0):

The '/' character is reserved for locating a folder. It would be better if you use a query.

A regular expression would be useful for a query.

```
//where frame is the iframe you showed above:
var query = JSON.parse(('{'+(frame.source.substr(1).replace(new RegExp("([^=]+)=([^&]+)&?",'g'),function(){return '"'+arguments[1]+'":"'+arguments[2]+'",';}))+'}').replace(/,\}/,"}"));
```

Anyway, I guess you could also use regular expressions for the format that you want. I just **strongly** urge you to use a query string.

```
var width = -1;
var height = -1;
...
//frame is the iframe that you show.
//You should consider adding an id attribute to that so that you can identify it later.
//It's good coding practice.
var results = frame.match(/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)$/);
if(results.length == 3)
{
   width=parseInt(results[1]);
   height=parseInt(results[2]);
}
else
{
   //something went wrong...
}
```

If you want to change the frame size, just call `replace()` instead of `match()`. Make sure you pass a function as described at the [EcmaScript standards](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.1).

To learn more about Regular Expressions in JavaScript, see [this webpage](http://www.visibone.com/regular-expressions/)