# Change Frame size with javascript in the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the size of an iframe with javascript according to the URL,

I mean that if the url is:

`mywebpage.com/example.html?width=(value1)&height=(value2)`

the iframe is

`<iframe width="(value1)" height="(value2)" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="http://mips.tv/embedplayer/test121/1/(value1)/(value2)"></iframe>`

I have an example here but its now working in the src values of the iframe

http://redzeronline.ucoz.com/xd.html?width=800&height=450

Comment: Please do not post [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257376/change-frame-propierties-with-javascript-in-the-url) twice.

Comment: No body has answered :(

Comment: There is one person who answered your question but deleted his answer. But that does not mean you can repost the same question. If you are not getting answers, edit your original question to clarify it and add more details into helping people solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var query = location.search.split('&');
var splitQuery = {};
for(var x in query)
{
var t = query[x].split('=');
splitQuery[t[0]] = t[1];
}
```

and look for what you want from there. If width and height are numbers, you shouldn't have trouble with that code.

Comment: Please answer the OP's [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257376/change-frame-propierties-with-javascript-in-the-url), not his duplicate.

Comment: i just what that to get the values like this `http://mips.tv/embedplayer/test121/1/(value1)/(value2)` where value 1 in the URL is width and value2 is height

Comment: Fine. I'll answer the original question.